# numpy.diff returning an empty array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
#python 3.6.3
import numpy as np

time_C0002A/1000 
array([[-0.99925  ], 
       [-0.99925  ], 
       [-0.99925  ], 
       ..., 
       [ 0.0181095], 
       [ 0.0195675], 
       [ 0.0205931]]) 

Fs_log = 1 / np.diff(time_C0002A/1000)
```

When I enter it in to see what it returns, it is given as an empty array

```
Fs_log 
array([], shape=(9063,0), dtype = float64)
```

I am expecting an array to be returned and have confirmed with a different example, any idea what could be occurring and how I should remedy this? i believe it is an issue with the axis along which diff is taken but I am not sure what it should be defined as, example:

```
np.diff(time_C0002A/1000, axis = 0)
```

But I am not sure? Input appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Your `time_C0002A` array has a shape of (n,1).  `np.diff` take the difference over the last axis by default, in your case of length 1.  You can specify the axis as an argument.

```
np.diff(time_C0002A/1000, axis=0)
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually just typed an edit before this answer, I appreciate it.